# Restoring Mac OS X (10.7.5)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

A old MacBook was given to me to develop an iPhone app. The problem is that the Mac was treated horribly and there is a lot of bloatware. It is currently running 10.7.5. I want to create a new user that does not use ANY of the applications so it runs completely separate as in none of the bloatware apps are shown/used. I can't restore the Mac completely as it's someone elses and I don't want to remove any of their files but still want to have a "restored account."

Comment: I would create the new user, then run the [App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).

Comment: @Deesbek I dont fully understand this. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new account, with *Parental Controls* setting.  Use the Parental Controls to only allow specific applications to run.  System-level programs (like anti-virus, or others) would still be running in the background; but, as far as normal applications go, you would know exactly what was being run and when.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I only need to be an administrator because i use terminal to install things a lot as well as install things in general.